# creating a dialog box on link click, javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dojo, popup

I would like to be able to launch a popup or dialog box when clicking on a link in my application - I want to add a horizontal slider to this window so the user can adjust the data displayed. I have been researchng various dijit widgets but am unsure of what will work, I have tried to test some of the widgets like dialog, TooltipDialog but have not gotten any results. i am also very new to javascript so my coding is not the greatest. I'm looking for some useful samples if anyone has suggestions. I tried to start with the sample code on the dojo website but haven't been able to get that to work either, I know I am missing something.

Here's an example below where I am just trying to create a dialog box off a button (code taken from dojo site), before testing with a link. I keep getting the error `myDialog is not defined`. Even when I put `var` before myDialog, I still get the same error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>

    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script>
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){
    var myDialog = new Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px"
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code.

1) Using the wrong styling.
The body tag has `claro` styling where as you have requested `tundra` in you link tag.

```
<body class="claro">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>
```

Need to change one of them.
change link tag to `claro` stylesheet. e.g

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/tundra/claro.css"/>
```

2. myDialog is locally scoped.

Any variable declared using a `var` keyword inside a function is only available within the function.

```
function(Dialog){
    var myDialog = new Dialog({...
}
```

Variable `myDialog` is not visible outside the function.
To make `myDialog` global you need to remove the `var` keyword.e.g

```
myDialog = new Dialog({....
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did change the stylesheet and also took away var before myDialog, but am still getting the same error: `myDialog is not defined.` I have also put the line `var  myDialog;` outside the function with the same results.

Comment: about the variable outside the function - i had changed the code to create a function on link click

Comment: thanks for that I've got it working now with a button, and now am trying to get it to run off a link click. I posted new code above - can't get the link click to work yet.

Comment: please do not mix/add/extend questions when you have accepted it as a answer. Post the link query as a new question, so that other members can have a look at it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kendo-ui.
Look for kendo-ui documenttion on google

Comment: thanks for the reply i'd rather not use something I have to pay for