# creating a dialog box on link click, javascript part 2

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, dojo, dialog

Thanks to Frank's answer to my original post [creating a dialog box on link click, javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897317/creating-a-dialog-box-on-link-click-javascript/26904900?noredirect=1#comment42375341_26904900) I got the sample code to launch a dialog from a button to work. Now I want to launch a dialog box from a link click. I've tried to add a function to the code that is run on a link click, but it just launches a blank page with a server error. What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>

    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

require(["dijit/Dialog", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog){

var myDialog2;

     myDialog = new Dialog({
        id: "MyDialog",
        title: "Adjust Transparency",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px"
    });


function showDialog() {
        myDialog2 = new Dialog({
        id: "MyDialog2",
        title: "Adjust Transparency",
        content: "Test content.",
        style: "width: 300px"
    });
    myDialog2.show();

}

});

    </script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>
    <a href="javascript:void();"onclick="showDialog();">show</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Here is updated code based the answer below, still getting same error `Uncaught ReferenceError: showDialog is not defined'`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>

    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider", "dijit/registry","dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog, HorizontalSlider, registry){

        var imageSlider = new HorizontalSlider({
                value: 7,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 10,
                intermediateChanges: true,
                discreteValues: 11,
                showButtons: true,
                style: "width:200px;",
                //onChange: lang.hitch(this, function(value) {
                    //imageServiceLayer.setOpacity(value / 10); 
                //})
            }, "imageSlider");
            imageSlider.startup();

     myDialog = new Dialog({
        id: "MyDialog",
        title: "Image Opacity",
        content: imageSlider,
        style: "width: 225px"
    });

    function showDialog(){
        var widget = registry.byId("MyDialog");
        widget.showDialog();
    }
});

    </script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="showDialog();">show</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Mistake is that you are using the `javascript:void(0)` wrong instead of

```
 <a href="javascript.void();"onclick="showDialog();">show</a>
```

you should do something that look like this

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="showDialog();">show</a>
```

Make sure that you don't put `;` in the end of void and insert a zero as a param

**UPDATE 2**

you need to create a method you can call it `showDialog`

so it will look like this:

```
function showDialog(){
  require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    var widget = registry.byId("MyDialog");
   widget.showDialog();
   });
 }
```

Add this function and this should not throw error and the dialog with the id `MyDialog` will appear

**UPDATE 3**

As frank said you need to put the showDialog in a function outside the require context and you need to call the right method to show the dialog.

your new code should look something like this I test it locally and it work 100%

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>

    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
```

//This is where you put the showDialog function outside the require.
     var  showDialog;

```
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider", "dijit/registry","dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog, HorizontalSlider, registry){

        var imageSlider = new HorizontalSlider({
                value: 7,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 10,
                intermediateChanges: true,
                discreteValues: 11,
                showButtons: true,
                style: "width:200px;",
                //onChange: lang.hitch(this, function(value) {
                    //imageServiceLayer.setOpacity(value / 10); 
                //})
            }, "imageSlider");
            imageSlider.startup();

     myDialog = new Dialog({
        id: "MyDialog",
        title: "Image Opacity",
        content: imageSlider,
        style: "width: 225px"
    });
//here you create the function
      showDialog = function(){

//and this is how you call the dialog to show, you did it right in the button but not inside the function
         myDialog.show();
    }
});

    </script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
    <button onclick="myDialog.show();">show</button>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="showDialog();">show</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and as sixtyfootersdude said you don't need to use the registry.byId I inserted there to let you understand that you can show the dialogbox outside of the context you are in if you know the ID, but anyway that is not the case.

This will work.

Comment: thanks I just noticed I didn't have the colon after javascript in the link. I did add the zero as you suggested, what does that mean? Still have the same error, showDialog is not defined

Comment: that is a different error you can't call the showDialog(); of  widget from an anchor tag without specifying which dialog you wan to open. i will update the answer for the second issue

Comment: I tried the code in your update2 but still gettting same error? I will post my updated code above

Comment: @KLD You are making the same mistake as in your previous question? You are defining the `showdialog` function inside another function. It thus has a local scope and is not visible to the `anchor` tag. You need to make it a  global function or assign it to a global variable.

Comment: how to make it a global function - declare var myFunction outside the function and then set it equal to the function?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would remove your dependency on the dijit registry.  This is a bad way to manage widgets.  I would update to this:

```
require(["dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Dialog, HorizontalSlider) {

    var imageSlider = new HorizontalSlider({
            ...
    }, "imageSlider");
    imageSlider.startup();

    myDialog = new Dialog({
            ...
    });

    function showDialog() {
        console.log("You already have a reference to dialog.  It is in the same closure as this.  Dialog", myDialog);
        myDialog.showDialog();
    }
});
```

Now you reported getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showDialog is not defined':

Is this on the `showDialog` function that you have defined or on `myDialog.showDialog`?